# request.getHeader("user-agent") JSP

Tags: jsp, navegador-web

Estoy usando la función `request.getHeader("user-agent")` con Chrome

Y me devuelve

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

¿Cómo puedo identificar el navegador exacto que se está usando ?

Comment: En la documentacion tienes un metodo `getName()` para el browser: http://bitwalker.eu/user-agent-utils-snapshot/javadoc/index.html

Comment: Esto me recuerda a [este artículo](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/), cuya traducción aproximada es [ésta](https://www.meneame.net/c/11055412)

Comment: Al final he usado este código que he encontrado :P

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser

Answer (score 1):

```
    String  browserDetails  =   request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    String  userAgent       =   browserDetails;
    String  user            =   userAgent.toLowerCase();

    String os = "";
    String browser = "";


     //===============Browser===========================
    if (user.contains("msie"))
    {
        String substring=userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")).split(";")[0];
        browser=substring.split(" ")[0].replace("MSIE", "IE")+"-"+substring.split(" ")[1];
    } else if (user.contains("safari") && user.contains("version"))
    {
        browser=(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Safari")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[0]+"-"+(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Version")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[1];
    } else if ( user.contains("opr") || user.contains("opera"))
    {
        if(user.contains("opera"))
            browser=(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Opera")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[0]+"-"+(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Version")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[1];
        else if(user.contains("opr"))
            browser=((userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("OPR")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-")).replace("OPR", "Opera");
    } else if (user.contains("chrome"))
    {
        browser=(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-");
    } else if ((user.indexOf("mozilla/7.0") > -1) || (user.indexOf("netscape6") != -1)  || (user.indexOf("mozilla/4.7") != -1) || (user.indexOf("mozilla/4.78") != -1) || (user.indexOf("mozilla/4.08") != -1) || (user.indexOf("mozilla/3") != -1) )
    {
        //browser=(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-");
        browser = "Netscape-?";

    } else if (user.contains("firefox"))
    {
        browser=(userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-");
    } else if(user.contains("rv"))
    {
        browser="IE-" + user.substring(user.indexOf("rv") + 3, user.indexOf(")"));
    } else
    {
        browser = "UnKnown, More-Info: "+userAgent;
    }

     if(!browser.startsWith("Chrome")){
        browser = "Estás usando " + browser + "Se recomienda usar Chrome";
    }
    out.println("Browser Name ==========>"+browser);
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser